# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

recently I imported facebook sdk to my game to be able to use facebook ads service. But after I imported it, I got this error:

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

while building. I am adding console errors to below. I can't figure out what is the problem.

Btw I am using unity hubs preferences.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Configure project :unityLibrary
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease

> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-13:31 Warning:
    uses-permission#android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:11 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-16:31 Warning:
    uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:14 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-19:31 Warning:
    uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:17 to remove other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease

C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\libs\unity-classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackManagerFactory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.unity3d.player.a.<init>(android.content.Context)`
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\libs\unity-classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnCompleteListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.unity3d.player.a$d` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\libs\unity-classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.AssetPackStateUpdateListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.unity3d.player.a$b` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\libs\unity-classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnCompleteListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.unity3d.player.a$e` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\libs\unity-classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.unity3d.player.a$c` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.

> Task :launcher:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
57 actionable tasks: 57 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

```
Note: C:\Users\aktas\Documents\GitHub\Casual-Puzzle-Game\Casual-Puzzle-Prototype\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 78457 > 65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
  Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 3m 18s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this answer:
[answer in unity fourm](https://forum.unity.com/threads/enable-multidex-support-for-unity-2020.990440/#post-7824879)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).